# Line break created by CSS margin add an extra pixel than using br element

Tags: html, css

The space created by an empty paragraphs with a `br` element inside occupies the same space as if the paragraph had content on it (as expected).

For example: This `div`:

```
<div style="line-height: 1.3">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p><br></p> <!-- `br` here -->
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
</div>
```

has the same height a this one:

```
<div style="line-height: 1.3">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <p>Three</p>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
</div>
```

But if instead of using a `br` element, I use a `div` with a `margin-top` of the same size as the `line-height`, the space created by the `div` becomes one pixel higher that its counterparts.

This `div` will ***not*** be the same height as the last two:

```
<div style="line-height: 1.3">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <div style="margin-top: 1.3em"></div>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
</div>
```

(Even using `<div style="height: 1.3em"></div>` will have the same extra pixel).

In order to make the `div` space as same as the others, I had to subtract one pixel from its `margin-top` (or `height`), like this:

```
<div style="line-height: 1.3">
  <p>One</p>
  <p>Two</p>
  <div style="margin-top: calc(1.3em - 1px)"></div>
  <p>Four</p>
  <p>Five</p>
</div>
```

**My question is**: What causes this extra pixel in the height of the space created by CSS?

Comment: Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: Both Chrome and Safari on Mac.

Comment: I tried it in my Browser (Firefox on Linux) an the first and the second divs are both 168px high, the third has a height of 136 !! pixels, so not just one pixel. I think thats because the <p> elements have a margin too and the margin-top of the div and the p's margin overlap in CSS by default. https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/

Comment: But I have tried reseting all the margins and padding with the universal selector in the CSS file and I still find a difference.

Comment: I tested a universal selector and now it shows the same height for all divs. I don't know what could cause the extra pixel you are seeing. Here is the code i used for testing: https://pastebin.com/sYUviw9Y

Comment: seems ok on my side as well: https://jsfiddle.net/h7yepwa8/

Comment: Interesting. I see that it works like that. But try this (which give me the same effect): https://jsfiddle.net/aj5q6yuz/ (The last two `div` are higher)

Comment: make the font-size bigger to understand that it's a sub-pixel rendring and rounding issue, nothing more

Comment: 1em in this case let's say would be 16px. 1.3em would be 16px * 1.3 =>  20.8px. So there could be some inconsistency between `line-height` and `margin-top` how browser will choose to display them 20px or 21px. Try 1.5em it should give you 16px * 1.5 => 24px. Interesting if it still would be an issue.